# Flex: Set Selected Value of RadioButton in CodeBehind

Tags: apache-flex, radio-button

I all I know how to select a default value in a Radio Button in the Mxml like this:

```
<ada:AdaRadioButton id="rbDDAACampNo" 

    selected="{Dto==null || Dto.field!='Y' || Dto.field==null}"
```

How can I apply this condition  in the codeBehind like `id.setSelected` or some similar method?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "the codeBehind"?  Are you looking to write code in a `<fx:Script>` block instead of mxml?

Comment: @Brian The CodeBehind is the Microsoft word used normally with WPF. If you have an AS3 class used as the base for your MXML then the class is the "CodeBehind". It would work the same as just having a script tag though.

Comment: @Drahcir You mean like the parent class in an inheritance tree?

Comment: @Brian yes, where the child class is the MXML document. The word comes from WPF where the view is automatically split into a XAML file and a C# file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in the AS

```
//this is the handler of the creation complete of the component.
onCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void{
    rbDDAACampNo.selected = Dto==null || Dto.field!='Y' || Dto.field==null;
}
```